# get element that is of class with specific href

Tags: jquery, href

This is the code I use to get element with a specific href value:

```
var myElement = $("a[href='http://www.stackoverflow.com']");
```

I would like to only get elements that are of class title. I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
var myElement = $(".title, a[href='http://www.stackoverflow.com']");
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: If you only want the <a> with a class title and your Href you should use: `$("a.title[href='http://www.stackoverflow.com']");`, if you don't want that, please be more specific about what you want to select

Comment: sorry, you would like to get a tags which has class called title? i mean, `<a href="foo"  class="title"> ... ` is what you want to get and `<a href="bar" > ... ` not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `,` and use a selector like

```
var myElement = $("a.title[href='http://www.stackoverflow.com']");
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/znxosdos/)

Above selector will select all `a` tags with a `class` of `.title` with `href` you've specified.

The reason your selector failed is because when you use a `,` it will select all `a` tags with that `href` value and all elements with a class of `.title` which is not what you are looking for. Hence we write `a.title` which will select the `a` only if they have a `title` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for get all *.title* with *href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'*

```
var myElement = $("a[href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'].title");
```

Class Selector (“.class”) https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/